# How do I integrate google authenticator in my app(nodeJS)?

Tags: google-authenticator

I have seen some web applications making use of Google Authenticator(i.e. 6 digit numeric code generator) as a 2nd level security measure(examples: Binance, Kraken etc). I am making an app on google cloud platform, and need that to use Authenticator.

How do I do this?

N/A

This has to be implemented on a nodeJS server

Comment: There are a couple questions on google authenticator, but they are not what I am looking for. Please dont mark duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Even tho this example might still work, it's using library **speakeasy** which is **no longer maintained**.

> good Example [google-authenticator-node-js-web-app](https://hackernoon.com/create-an-angular-7-google-authenticator-node-js-web-app-with-two-factor-authentication-95e87af9356b)

```
> mkdir back-end
> cd back-end
> npm init -y
> npm install --save express body-parser cors qrcode speakeasy
```

Now, we have created a directory ‘back-end’ and initialized it as a `Node.js` project by installing the following dependencies:

**express** — This is a minimal and flexible web framework for creating API services.
body-parser — In order to parse the HTTP method’s body data, this package is being used.

**cors** — This package is used in order to enable the client side web application to communicate with the API services and to avoid the cross-origin issue.

**qrcode** — In this application we would be generating the QR-code as a base64 image data, and thus we require qrcode package.

**speakeasy** — This is the package that enables our application to provide with the secret key and the T-OTP algorithm that the Google Authenticator uses and is also useful for the verification of the Auth code being provided.

We will now create a few API services, with app.js as the main file of execution. For the simplicity of learning process, separation of concerns is followed for the scaffolding of the application.

Comment: speakeasy  seems to be no longer maintained, is there alternative ?